# Ansible yum update --security

Tags: ansible

I'm working with the yum module on ansible.
I'm trying to do what would be on RHEL yum update --security
My Ansible playbook looks like

```
 tasks:
   - name: checking updates
     yum:
             list: security
     register: output
     become: true

   - debug:
         msg: "{{ output }}"
```

the output it's

```
"msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "results": []
    }
```

what I'm looking it's something like

```
11 package(s) needed for security, out of 204 available

kernel.x86_64                                             3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
kernel-devel.x86_64                                       3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
kernel-headers.x86_64                                     3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
kernel-tools.x86_64                                       3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                                  3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
libicu.x86_64                                             50.2-4.el7_7                                     rhel-7-server-rpms
python-perf.x86_64                                        3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7                             rhel-7-server-rpms
tomcat-el-2.2-api.noarch                                  7.0.76-11.el7_7                                  rhel-7-server-rpms
tomcat-jsp-2.2-api.noarch                                 7.0.76-11.el7_7                                  rhel-7-server-rpms
tomcat-lib.noarch                                         7.0.76-11.el7_7                                  rhel-7-server-rpms
tomcat-servlet-3.0-api.noarch                             7.0.76-11.el7_7                                  rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Using the shell module it actually gives me back the result but as an error due that I shouldn't be using shell module

```
 #   - name: checking update with shell
         #     shell: "yum --security check-update"
         #     register: shel_outp
         #     become: true

         #   - debug:
         #           msg: "{{ shel_outp.stdout }}"
```

does anyone have a solution for this kind of issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi diego, welcome to SO. You will want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60854981/edit) because no one can possibly read what you're trying to do with all that sea of text. The edit dialog has a helpful reference for how to use the formatting markup here. Good luck

Comment: Thanks mdaniel, I didn't see that everything was a plain text instead of pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want [`security: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/yum_module.html#parameter-security), as it [appends `--security`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.0/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum.py#L1516) to the `yum` command

Based on your question, it looks like you are merely interested in *knowing* what would change, which is what [`check_mode: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks) is designed to do; thus:

```
 tasks:
   - name: checking updates
     yum:
       security: yes
       state: latest
     check_mode: yes
     register: yum_output
     become: true

   - name: show that yum output
     debug:
       var: yum_output
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code and you need to set the `name: '*'` parameter, otherwise it will not show you anything - at least in my Ansible version `ansible [core 2.11.4]`

```
- name: checking updates
  yum:
    name: '*'
    security: yes
    state: latest
  check_mode: yes
  register: yum_output
```

thanks!
cheers Ringo

Comment: My command kept doing nothing until I added `name: '*'` -- thanks!